# ifort compile executable linux undefined reference to

Tags: linux, makefile, fortran

I have the following makefile

```
#makefile for building Linux 64b executable
FC = ifort
MPPD = -DAUTODOUBLE -4R8 -4I8
FLAGS = -safe_cray_ptr -assume byterecl,buffered_io,protect_parens -warn nousage -zero -ftz -fp-model precise -mP2OPT_hpo_dist_factor=21 -diag-disable 10212,10010 -fimf-arch-consistency=true -traceback -pad -DLINUX -DIFORT -DNET_SECURITY -DADDR64 -DINTEL -DXEON64 -DFCC80 -DTIMER=cycle_time -DSSE2 -DOVERRIDE -DMPP -DMPICH -DHPMPI -DAUTODOUBLE -DNEWIO -DEXTENDED -DLSTCODE  -DENABLE_HASH3 -DFFTW -DZMF2 -DUSES_CXX -DPFEM -DSPRNG -DUSE_SPRNG -DUSES_CPP  -DPTHREADS -nodps -i8 -r8 -DSPRNG_MPI -DUSE_MPI -DINTEL -DAdd_ -xSSE2 -align array16byte -fPIC -O2

TARGET = mppdyna

MPICH_LIB = /opt/intel/impi/4.1.3.048/mic/lib/libmpi.so

MPICH_INC = /opt/intel/impi/4.1.3.048/mic/include/

FFLAGS = $(FLAGS) -I. -I$(MPICH_INC) -I/opt/ibm/platform_mpi/include/

LINKLIBS = libgcrypt.so.20 libgpg-error.so.0 libpthread.so.0 libtriboformplugin.so 

OBJS = dyn21.o dyn21b.o couple2other_user.o triboform_lsdyna_plugin.o 

$(TARGET): $(OBJS)
    $(FC) -w -o mppdyna.out $(OBJS) $(LINKLIBS)

init_dyn21.o: init_dyn21.f nhisparm.inc 
    $(FC) -c $(FFLAGS) init_dyn21.f
dyn21.o: dyn21.f nhisparm.inc
    $(FC) -c $(FFLAGS) dyn21.f
dyn21b.o: dyn21b.f nhisparm.inc
    $(FC) -c $(FFLAGS) dyn21b.f
couple2other_user.o: couple2other_user.f
    $(FC) -c $(FFLAGS)  couple2other_user.f
dynrfn_user.o: dynrfn_user.f
    $(FC) -c $(FFLAGS) dynrfn_user.f
triboform_lsdyna_plugin.o: triboform_lsdyna_plugin.f
    $(FC) -c $(FFLAGS) triboform_lsdyna_plugin.f

clean:
    -@rm mppdyna 2>/dev/null || :
    rm -rf *.o
```

And it gives me the following error message

```
...
...
dyn21b.f:(.text+0x90cd2): undefined reference to `adios_'
dyn21b.o: In function `umat48c_':
dyn21b.f:(.text+0x90dc2): undefined reference to `adios_'
dyn21b.o:dyn21b.f:(.text+0x90eb2): more undefined references to `adios_' follow
dyn21b.o: In function `thumat12_':
dyn21b.f:(.text+0x961ed): undefined reference to `crvval_'
dyn21b.f:(.text+0x96260): undefined reference to `crvval_'
dyn21b.o: In function `thumat13_':
dyn21b.f:(.text+0x963bc): undefined reference to `adios_'
...
...
libtriboformplugin.so: undefined reference to `do_license_check'
libtriboformplugin.so: undefined reference to `write_processing_file'
libtriboformplugin.so: undefined reference to `strerror_s'
libtriboformplugin.so: undefined reference to `fopen_s'
libtriboformplugin.so: undefined reference to `freopen_s'
make: *** [mppdyna] Error 1
```

I'm relatively new with ifort, can anyone point to me where my fault is?
`which ifort` points to /opt/intel/composer_xe_2013_sp1.2.144/bin/intel64/ifort and I'm also using platform_mpi. 
I've created libtriboformplugin.so with another makefile (succesfully) that's from a C project.

Comment: Where are the undefined function ? In which library ? Located where ?

Comment: Procedures adios, crvval would need to be found in the sources you build or libraries you designate for linking. Link order matters, at least for static libraries and objects.  As you are usi

Comment: Commercial application is better dealt with by vendor' assistance. Your problems don't look to be specific to ifort.

Comment: @PTRK in the case of for example `libtriboformplugin.so`, they're located therein.

Comment: @tim18 thanks, i will go from there